# 'Any?' does not conform to 'Decodable'

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I have `DataModel` data type:

```
class DataModel: Decodable {
    var data : Any?
    var name : String?
}
```

server json:

```
{
   "data":"success",
   "name":"john"
}
```

or

```
{
    "data": {
        "result": {
            "shopcode": 0,
            "shopname": ""
        }
    },
    "name": "john"
}
```

the `data` property I not sure type, sometime is `[String: Any]` or `String` or `null`.
I search some answer, but it not I want, so please don't set question [duplicate]
[How to decode a property with type of any arbitrary JSON dictionary in Swift 4 decodable protocol](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80288)
   [Any when decoding JSON with Codable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279992/any-when-decoding-json-with-codable)

How to solve this? Have any way let data property decoder to `[String: Any]`, `String`, `nil`?

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors

Comment: `Any` cannot be used in `Codable` protocol because it requires type information beforehand. [check answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48297432/2857130)

Comment: Share with us what `data` looks like in both cases: as a `String` and as `[String:Any]`

Comment: `Codable` relies on concrete types. If the JSON contains different types for a key you have to write a custom initializer which handles the cases.

Comment: @vadian yes,I think so.I maybe can write extension or orrwrite Decodable solve this